# How to compare data in two columns of different sheets to find duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel

> I have two excel Sheets **SheetA** and **SheetB**. Both sheets have
>   thousands values. Some values are same in a Column **"Numbers"** in
>   **SheetA** and in a column **"No."** in **SheetB**. Now I want to make an extra column in **SheetA** with name **"Duplicate"** which
>   would have only duplicated or repeated values of **SheetA** column
>   **"Numbers"** and **SheetB** column **"No."** How is it possible...? 
>   Images are given below
>
> Thanks
>   [image]
>   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Paste the below formula in your F2 cell of SheetA. Then copy it to other cells.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1, COUNTIF(SheetB!C:C,B2)>1),B2,"")
```